# 3rd term of binomial expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-distribution

Given the expression $(x+y)^8$ where $x=0.3$ and $y=0.7$, I'm trying to find the numerical value of the 3rd term. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: The third term would be $\binom{8}{2}x^2y^6$ or $\binom{8}{2}y^2x^6$. So evaluate this and pick the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plug in $x = .3$ and $y = .7$, then $(x+y) = 1$ and the expansion is simply $1$.

Are you seeking ${8 \choose 3} x^5 y^3 = 56\ \cdot 0.3^5\ 0.7^3 = 0.0466754$

or

${8 \choose 2} x^6 y^2 = 28\ \cdot 0.3^6\ 0.7^2 = 0.0100019$?

Comment: 0.0100019 is what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork You should delete your comment now.